# Can't write TO_NUMBER

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, string-conversion

I have numbers saved in table as string, for example

```
25758313,1
200000000
1418213,04
```

I know that there is 1) always no group separator; 2) comma as decimal separator, if needed; 3) no more that 2 decimal chars.

Triyng to create view with columns defined as to_number(string_val), but can write correct expression.

Comment: This is another good example why you should **never** store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunatelly, I can not decide how to store data. At least now.

Comment: Try something like `SELECT TO_NUMBER(col, '999999999D9999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='', ''') FROM table`. Note: The third parameters use two single quotes (or even three at the end) and there is a space after the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual page for `TO_NUMBER()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm) has an example you can adapt:

> The `'nlsparam'` argument in this function has the same purpose as it
>   does in the `TO_CHAR` function for number conversions.
>
> ```
> SELECT TO_NUMBER('-AusDollars100','L9G999D99',
>    ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''
>      NLS_CURRENCY            = ''AusDollars''
>    ') "Amount"
>      FROM DUAL;
> ```

It could be something like:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT '25758313,1' AS original_text FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT '200000000' FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT '1418213,04' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT original_text,
TO_NUMBER(original_text, '999999999999D999999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') AS parsed_number
FROM data;
```

```
ORIGINAL_T PARSED_NUMBER
---------- -------------
25758313,1    25758313.1
200000000      200000000
1418213,04    1418213.04
```

Comment: Thank you. I trying few combination of mask and NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS but this one works!